# Qual a diferença entre usar uma div e React.Fragment?

Tags: javascript, react

Estou estudando React mais a fundo e em um dos cursos que estou acompanhando é citado o uso do `<React.Fragment>` para renderizar vários elementos de uma vez.

Normalmente nos meus componentes eu utilizo uma `<div>`:

```
<div>
   <h6>Olá mundo</h6>
   <h3>Até logo</h3>
</div>
```

Mas vi que também é possível com:

```
<React.Fragment>
   <h6>Olá mundo</h6>
   <h3>Até logo</h3>
</React.Fragment>
```

Quais as vantagens de se utilizar o `<React.Fragment>` em comparação com uma `<div>`?

Em quais casos é apropriado utilizar a `<div>` e em quais casos devo utilizar o `Fragment`?

Comment: Você também pode usar `<>` e `</>` no lugar da tag `<React.Fragment>`. O efeito é o mesmo, mas fica mais fácil de ver o código e perceber que aquele elemento não será renderizado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como você deve saber, o [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) é um mero açúcar sintático. Não faz parte da especificação do ECMAScript. Assim, quando compilado, o JSX se torna algo mais ou menos assim:

```js
React.createElement(component, props, ...children);
```

Portanto, agora entendemos a necessidade de só se retornar um elemento React por componente. Isto é válido, já que retorna somente um elemento:

```js
function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <strong>Foo</strong>
      <span>Bar</span>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Contudo, este outro exemplo já não é válido, já que um componente não pode retornar mais de dois elementos:

```js
function MyComponent() {
  // ❗️ Errado!
  return (
    <strong>Foo</strong>
    <span>Bar</span>
  );
}
```

Desse modo, se você precisar retornar mais de dois elementos em um mesmo nível, o React obriga-o a envolvê-los em um único componente. Anteriormente à introdução dos fragmentos, você deveria utilizar uma tag do HTML ou algum outro componente genérico, o que nem sempre era ideal, já que seria inserido mais um elemento HTML no DOM, podendo inclusive afetar a acessibilidade ou dificultar a componentização tão importante para o React.

A [documentação sobre fragmentos](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) explica essas [motivações](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#motivation) com um pouco mais de aprofundamento.

> Quais as vantagens de se utilizar o `<React.Fragment>` em comparação com uma `<div>`?

Conforme colocado acima, a principal vantagem de se utilizar um fragmento é o fato de você poder retornar múltiplos elementos a um mesmo nível sem necessariamente ter que envolvê-los em algum componente que irá renderizar algum nó no DOM.

Por exemplo, no trecho abaixo, uma `<div>` será renderizada:

```js
function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <strong>Foo</strong>
      <span>Bar</span>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.body);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Mas neste outro exemplo, nenhuma outra tag além de `strong` e `span` serão inseridas no DOM, já que um fragmento foi utilizado:

```js
function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <strong>Foo</strong>
      <span>Bar</span>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.body);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

> Em quais casos é apropriado utilizar a `<div>` e em quais casos devo utilizar o `Fragment`?

Utilize a `div` — ou qualquer outro componente que irá renderizar algo na árvore do DOM — quando você quiser que isso aconteça. Se você não quiser que o componente que "envolve" seja renderizado no DOM, utilize um fragmento.