# Elementos JSX incluidos em closing tag

Tags: javascript, react, jsx, react-dom

Ao criar a div com o nome de SERVIÇOS exibe o seguinte erro:

> `Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>?`

```
<div id="start">
    <div className="head-logo">
        <img src={logoBlack} alt="FlowsLabs Logo" />
    </div>
    <h1>Nós desenvolvemos soluções inteligentes e eficientes. <br></br>
     Para todos os tipos de negócios.</h1>
    <div className="container">
    </div>
    <p>&darr;</p>
</div>
<div className="services">
    <h1>Teste</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Qual a diferença entre usar uma div e React.Fragment?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/446977/69296)

Answer (score 0):

O erro diz que todos os elementos devem estar dentro de uma tag apenas.

A sua `div` com a `className="services"` está fora da `div` com o `id="start"`. Coloque-a para dentro da `div` `start`.

Comment: Muito obrigado!